# How to disable Google AdSense script based on boolean value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, adsense

I run the same code on two websites. One website should contain Google AdSense block, when another shouldn't. Is there any way to disable Google AdSense on the second site, if `showGoogleAd` is false?

JavaScript:

```
var showGoogleAd = false;
```

HTML:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- vkkar.ru -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-1234567890123456"
     data-ad-slot="1234567890"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

I know that I can load script based on boolean value -

```
if (showGoogleAd) { 
    $.getScript('//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js', function(){});
```

But what should I do with remaining part? Or, can I just leave it?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/28/the-best-way-to-load-external-javascript/ in general the idea is to load external script programmatically. Which you can control based on your boolean  value

Comment: @YuriyGalanter, thanks. Now the question is with remaining part.

Comment: you can hide it using this code `$( ".adsbygoogle" ).hide();`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is enough to remove the following line from the html:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

and load it with JavaScript, if ad should be shown -

```
if (showGoogleAd) { 
   $.getScript("//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i test it on my website to disable Google AdSense, i use below script that remove ads ?

```
*

<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- Resposive_TEST -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle responsive-test"
  data-ad-client="ca-pub-3086914080036003"
  data-ad-slot="1408862175"
  data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script><pre> <code>
```

*